# Firebase appcheck preventing iphone from accessing fiestore

Tags: iphone, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-app-check

I recently added appcheck to my flutter app, it was blocking requests in debug mode without the tokens but in release mode, only my android phone is allowed to access firestore. I have an iphone SE, in good condition but firebase or apple device check/app attest is preventing access. I've followed all the steps here [App Check Flutter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/default-providers?hl=en&authuser=1) but still not working. I created a new key, uploaded it to firebase and added the key id, doesn't work. I have multiple keys though, should I use only one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who've also tried everything, this should solve your issue in release/production:

I checked the official flutterfire example and looks like there were no changes to `AppDelegate.swift` or any other files. There's a file I saw though in `firebase_app_check/example/ios/Runner/` called `RunnerRelease.entitlements` with these contents

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.devicecheck.appattest-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The official firebase docs at [Get started using App Check in Flutter apps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/default-providers) make no mention of creating this file manually but it's somehow in the example on [github](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_app_check/firebase_app_check/example/ios/Runner).